# "location.assign(url)" sometimes appears to lead to a wrong URL on mobile, though works fine in most cases

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have a page with a timeout - it must automatically redirect to another, specific URL, say "http://example.com/?x=1", 60 minutes after loading.
So I simply added `setTimeout(function() { location.assign('http://example.com/?x=1'); }, 60000);` to the page's JavaScript.
Usually this works just fine, but sometimes it ends up at "http://example.com/", losing the 'x' parameter somehow. This probably happens only on mobile browsers. One user reported the same problem on desktop, but it might have been a fluke. I'm guessing that it happens because a mobile browser left idle for an hour may get killed by OS and when I reopen it, it goes to the homepage by default. But why? Isn't it supposed to remember the full URL and get back to it after reactivation? Something doesn't make sense.
Has anyone encountered such a problem or has any idea why this might be happening? This happens on various platforms and browsers.

Yes, I know that I can probably fix this using a cookie or a session-wide variable or something, but I need to understand why this particular problem is happening. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I noticed here.  First - you say 60 minutes, but `60000` is only 60 seconds :) On why you'd lose the querystring on setting location ... that's super weird and I have no idea why it would happen.  The good news is, maybe you don't need JavaScript for this at all?  You can use a meta tag!

```html
<!-- Redirect page after 3 seconds -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=https://www.mozilla.org">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: You're right, it should've been 60*60000, not 60000. That's not the problem, of course. As for a meta-tag, I thought about it, but there are various difficulties with this solution and I'd rather not use it, unless as a last resort. I have more suitable solutions, as I mentioned, but that's not the point here.